# Selenium Server 2.17.0 SessionCleanup after few hours

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am always getting `SessionCleanup` after few hours. Because of the `SessionCleanup`, the test fails and Selenium is closed.

How do I stop executing `SessionCleanup`?

I found this but it is not fixed as mentioned:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3161

This error is in version 2.16.0 and 2.17.0

```
23.1.2012 9:48:52 org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid server
23.1.2012 9:48:55 org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer doStart
INFO: Version Jetty/5.1.x
23.1.2012 9:48:55 org.openqa.jetty.util.FileResource <clinit>
INFO: Checking Resource aliases
23.1.2012 9:48:57 org.openqa.jetty.util.Container start
INFO: Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.WebApplicationHandler@5e176f
23.1.2012 9:48:57 org.openqa.jetty.util.Container start
INFO: Started WebApplicationContext[/,/]
21.1.2012 9:48:57 org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener start
INFO: Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4455
23.1.2012 9:48:57 org.openqa.jetty.util.Container start
INFO: Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@1971afc
23.1.2012 12:59:22 SessionCleanup
WARNING: session ext. key 1327135735339 has TIMED OUT and will be released
```

Comment: It seems that the fact that session cleanup is running is not the problem (it should run every now and then), but it decides that `session ext. key 1327135735339 has TIMED OUT`. Some questions: Did you check that the session cleanup is really the cause (i.e. occurs before the test failing)? Does it always occur when you are running the same test? Also, looking at the log, it is not '2 hours' but 3 hours and 10 minutes.

Comment: This article mentions: 'The default timeout was 30000sec instead of 30sec. Should be fixed now.' -> http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.selenium.devel/6787 . Another possibility: are you closing clients after a test has finished? Maybe you have a lot of lingering clients and the server is running out of resources?

Comment: yes i check again and problem is session cleanup. When session is cleaned i get timed out.

Comment: can i prevent session cleanup? before this happened everything works ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control and maximize the `cleanupCycle` at the client level when launching the node with the option `-cleanupCycle 2147483647` (Java MAX_INT). According to the documentation, it doesn't look like you can prevent it entirely, but this will at least reduce the frequency to once every ~25 days if you have no other option.

Execute your jar with this command to see more options:
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.16.0.jar -help`